# Datepicker  not displaying in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker, internet-explorer-9

A client wants to have a internal form for his company and uses IE9. The problem is that datepicker doesn't show up in IE9. The only thing I get is the top of the datepicker UI (height is approximately 5px).

Screenshot:

[image]

Snippets of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'focus',
    beforeShowDay: function(date)
    { return [(date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 4), ""]; }
    },
    $.datepicker.regional['nl']);
    });
</script>
```

and

```
<li>
<label for="datum">Datum</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="datum" value="" class="datepicker" name="datum" placeholder="Datum" class="required"/>
</li>
```

Has anybody any idea why the datepicker UI doesn't show up?

Kind regards.

Comment: Can you please post the full code - maybe at jsfiddle.net?  Did you include the jquery-ui css assets?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this in any other browser??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/meUjE/ your code in a jsfiddle, the code you posted doesn't have the same error, can you try to recreate the issue on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @MarkSherretta index.php: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WQsnMmNG and js/control.js: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Gb0Gzqw0

Comment: @mdmullinax just posted 2 sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) in your [provided](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WQsnMmNG) source. The error is ocurring in [control.js](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Gb0Gzqw0).

edit:

Add the proper dependencies:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

remove:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```